# MySQL - 1300 - Invalid utf8 character string on update

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

I have a MySQL table column that I'm trying to convert from latin1 to UTF8.  Some of the values in the column are UTF8 already, but they are being stored as latin1, which results in some strange looking text.  Switching the column over is pretty straight forward, all I have to do is:

```
ALTER TABLE `user_profiles` MODIFY `last_name` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

The next step would be converting any now doubly encoded columns back to UTF8.  I can get a list of all those columns by running the following command:

```
SELECT `last_name`, CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(`last_name` USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8) AS `converted_last_name`
FROM `user_profiles`
WHERE (CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(`last_name` USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8)) IS NOT NULL
AND CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(`last_name` USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8) != `last_name`;
```

Which gives me something like:

```
| last_name       | converted_last_name  |
| ----------------|----------------------|
| çŽ‹ç»´é›„       | 王维雄                |
| niÃ±o de rivera | niño de rivera       |
| ThÃ¶lix         | Thölix               |
```

Looks good.  Now's when things get weird though.  If I run the update command:

```
UPDATE `user_profiles`
SET `last_name` = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(`last_name` USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8)
WHERE (CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(`last_name` USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8)) IS NOT NULL 
AND CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(`last_name` USING latin1) AS BINARY) USING utf8) != `last_name`
```

I get a `1300` error like this:

```
#1300 - Invalid utf8 character string: 'E36F'
```

Any idea why the update is different than the select?  Any thoughts on how to get around this issue?

Comment: In your database they use latin1...in your query you formated the data to have a desirable output...but in your update some utf8 characters are not suported by the latin1 character set . Your table is still in latin1

Comment: @RobertRozas not sure I'm following.  Doesn't the `ALTER TABLE` command I initially run convert the values to UTF8?  That's what they're doubly encoded in the first place, no?

Comment: Also, I tried converting the entire table to UTF8 and then running the update.  Still getting the same error though.

Comment: And creating a temp table with the select query content and then updating based on the temp table values.

Comment: Nope, throws the same error when I try to create the temporary table.

Comment: The temp table is with utf8 character set and collation, right?....or make this test: if you use the same collation and character set of your original data in the temp table, and if you populate that temp table with a simple select with no data conversion, works ok, or dont?